# Grails lazy inilitilization error when a user has to log back in

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Consider the situation when a user is logged in. After a specific time of idle period, the user's session expires and they are asked to log back in and the user is redirected back to the desired page. When they land on the page, I'm getting the `Lazy Initialization Error`

How can I make a session expire act like a log out (which doesn't raise lazy initialization errors) in regards to GORM, but still redirect back to the desired page?

Note: I am using Spring Security plugin.

(It seems overkill to go back and reattach all the GORM objects to a Hibernate session here, which is the advice I've seen around the web.)

Comment: where do you store this objects that are expiring? in webapp session?

Comment: Can you please provide stacktrace